React Native Expo - Button disappear when tested on APK build
I'm facing critical differences between the development version and the build version of my React Native app only on Android using Expo. The main issues I'm encountering is that the close button visible in the development version is missing in the build version (and other smaller UI problems)
Here are the 2 screens:
Development Version (Expo Go)

Build version

Here is the relevant code that handles the double-tap gesture and the UI rendering:
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef, useCallback } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Dimensions, Image, TouchableWithoutFeedback, TouchableOpacity } from 'react-native';
// libraries
import { CameraView, useCameraPermissions } from 'expo-camera';
import { Button, Divider, IconButton } from 'react-native-paper';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
// components
import CustomDashedLine from '../components/CustomDashline';

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------

const { height: DEVICE_HEIGHT, width: DEVICE_WIDTH } = Dimensions.get('window');

// ----------------------------------------------------------------------

const CameraScreen = ({ navigation, route }) => {
 
  const [isTakingPicture, setIsTakingPicture] = useState(false);
  const [showPrompt, setShowPrompt] = useState(true);
  const tapRef = useRef(null);

  const handleDoubleTap = useCallback(() => {
    if (tapRef.current !== null) {
      clearTimeout(tapRef.current);
      setShowPrompt(false);
      tapRef.current = null;
    } else {
      tapRef.current = setTimeout(() => {
        tapRef.current = null;
      }, 200);
    }
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    setShowPrompt(true);
  }, [step]);

  const takePicture = async () => {
    // take the pic and send with API
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableOpacity 
        style={{ flex: 1, zIndex: 1 }}
        onPress={!showPrompt ? takePicture : null} 
        disabled={isTakingPicture}
        activeOpacity={1}
      >
        <CameraView
          style={styles.camera}
          type='back'
          ref={(ref) => {camera = ref}}
        >
          <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
            <IconButton // <--- This button here
              icon={() => <Icon name="close" size={30} color="white" />}
              size={40}
              onPress={() => {
                navigation.goBack();
                setEnableTorch(false)
              }}
              style={styles.iconButton}
            />
          </View>
          {showPrompt && (
            <TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={handleDoubleTap}>
              <View style={styles.fullScreenTouchable}>
                <View style={styles.promptContainer}>
                  <Text style={styles.promptText}>A Text here</Text>
                  <Image source={imageUrl} />
                </View>
              </View>
            </TouchableWithoutFeedback>
          )}
          {!showPrompt && (
            <View style={styles.overlay}>
              <CustomDashedLine style={styles.cropLine}/>
              <CustomDashedLine style={styles.cropLine}/>
            </View>
          )}
        </CameraView>
      </TouchableOpacity>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
  camera: {
    flex: 1,
    width: '100%',
    height: '100%',
  },
  buttonContainer: {
    position: 'absolute',
    right: 20,
    bottom: 20,
    alignSelf: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    zIndex: 10,
    backgroundColor: 'transparent',
  },
  iconButton: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)',
    borderRadius: 50,
  },
  text: {
    fontSize: 24,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    color: 'white',
  },
  divider: {
    backgroundColor: 'white',
    width: 2,
    height: 200,
    marginVertical: 25,
    opacity: 0.5,
  },
  fullScreenTouchable: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    zIndex: 1,
  },
  promptContainer: {
    backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7)',
    padding: 20,
    borderRadius: 10,
    transform: [{ rotate: '90deg' }],
  },
  promptText: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 18,
    textAlign: 'center',
    transform: [{ scaleX: -1 }]
  },
  overlay: {
    position: 'absolute',
    top: 0,
    left: 0,
    right: 0,
    bottom: 0,
  },
  cropLine: {
    position: 'absolute',
    left: '20%',
    width: '70%',
  },
});


export default CameraScreen;


I'm not too familiar with React Native, but in Android typically when you see differences between debug and release builds, proguard rules are commonly the cause. Most libraries which rely on annotations and other resources require you to add specific proguard rules for release builds. Check the documentation for Expo, have they specified anything? And if the close button is in your own package, do you need to provide specific rules to ensure they are packaged in the release build and not removed when minification happens.

@omz1990 interesting im gonna check right now!
